# How to select multiple buttons and extract their values in Bootstrap by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created multiple buttons as follows->

```
               <label class="mx-3 my-2">
                <input type="button" class="option-input radio" name="example" checked/>
                  Translator
                </label>
                <label class="mx-3 my-2">
                  <input type="button" class="option-input radio" name="example" />
                  Proofreader
                </label>
                <label class="mx-3 my-2">
                  <input type="button" class="option-input radio" name="example" />
                  Content Writer
                </label>
                 <label class="mx-3 my-2">
                    <input type="button" class="option-input radio" name="example" />
                    Manager
                  </label>
```

I want to create a function in which I can select multiple buttons and whenever I select a button its values should append in a list.
Like if I have selected first and second option , I should get the list of first two values i.e. translator and proofreader.

How could I create it?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML you posted are buttons, that should be corrected to "checkbox". Then you said "I select a button its values should append in a list". In your HTML there is no button, so I added one. Finally, you didn't say how this list is displayed nor is there anything in your HTML that can display this list, so I added a `<div>` container that will hold the list. With those points made, your HTML (without bootstrap) looks like this:

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"  name="translator" checked/>
  Translator
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="proofreaderxample" />
  Proofreader
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="contentwriter" />
  Content Writer
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="manager" />
  Manager
</label>

<br><br>
 
<!-- this is the button the user needs to click on to get the values of the checkbox inputs -->
<input type="button" id="btnGetOptions" value="Get Options">

<br><br>

<!-- this is where the list is shown -->
<div id="txtSelectedOptions"></div>
```

The script to get this checked list is fairly easy. There are many examples of how to do this in StackOverflow, but for your specific HTML it would be this (added comments to help you understand what is happening):

```js
// creates a click event listener for the Get Options button
document.querySelector('#btnGetOptions').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // gets all the checkbox input elements that are checked or "ticked"
  var checkbox_inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  // gets all the checked or "ticked" values in an array from each input element
  var ticked_values = Array.from(checkbox_inputs).map(function(item) {return item.parentElement.innerText.trim();});
  // outputs the value of the checked or "ticked" checkboxes into an element with the id of "txtSelectedOptions"
  document.querySelector('#txtSelectedOptions').innerHTML = 'Selected Options:<br>' + ticked_values.join(', ');
});
```

You can see working example (without bootstrap) here:
https://jsfiddle.net/k6j08f9z/

---

Please note that in the future, when asking these types of questions in StackOverflow make sure to look around for similar questions. If you cannot find something that is like your question, then put some extra details into your question before asking or follow the posting a question walkthrough carefully. Low effort questions like yours usually do not get (very good) answers.